# Updating iPhone app for 3.1

Tags: iphone

I've just launched a new iPhone app and stupidly built it for 3.1.3 only as a minimum requirement. I can rebuild the app for 3.1, but where do I change that in iTunes Connect? Will it just pick it up from the app bundle that its minimum is 3.1 ?

Any advice very welcome :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build your app against the latest SDK (3.1.3 at time of writing), and then set your deployment target setting in your target's build settings to the lowest value of the OS that you wish to support.

Since you're linking against a 3.x SDK you can set your deployment target to 3.0.

If you wish to support anything lower than 3.0 you can set the deployment target to 2.x but then you need to remember to conditionally use any newer API functionality by checking if function names exist by comparing them with NULL and using the methods

```
respondsToSelector:
```

and

```
instancesRespondToSelector
```

You can use the Apple sample code for sending email within your app to see how this works.

Comment: Thanks - and this will change the minimum requirements in the App Store?

Comment: Yes. As far as I'm aware, the only requirements you can explicitly set in iTunes Connect is what type of device the app will run on, (iPod Touch, iPhone, etc). The version of the OS that the app will run on is decided by the deployment target setting.